# Not receiving OTP from Firebase Phone Auth(India)

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an android app which uses signIn from Firebase Phone Auth.I was previosly using email verification , that worked like charm, now i'm migrating to Phone Auth on the same project. I'm writing my auth on a Fragment, when i was following the givenlink https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth, i got compilation error saying "None of the following functions can be called with arguments supplied" ON "PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber", Following is the code,

gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

    apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.sstech.racemanager"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        // Enables data binding.
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        // def versions
        def nav_version = "2.1.0"
        def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"

    //    kapt("groupId:artifactId:version")
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        // Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'

        // Add the SDKs for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
        // For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'

        // Fragment
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

        // LifeCycle
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
        kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

        // Circle Image View
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    }
```

Fragment Class

```
    class RegisterPage : Fragment() {
        lateinit var binding: FragmentRegisterBinding
        lateinit var callbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
        lateinit var otpPin: String
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
                R.layout.fragment_register,container,false)

            binding.loginAlready.setOnClickListener { view: View->
                view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_registerPage_to_logPage)
            }

            binding.register.setOnClickListener {
                    registerAUser(binding)

            }

            binding.loginImage.setOnClickListener{
                    selectimage()

            }

    //        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_registerPage_to_logPage)


            return binding.root
        }

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        }

        private fun selectimage(){
    //        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY)
    ////        intent.type="image/*"
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type="image/*"
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"pick an image"),0)

        }
            var selectedImageUri : Uri?= null

        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            Toast.makeText(activity,"entered result",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            if(requestCode==0 && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){
                // image ok
                try {
                     selectedImageUri = data.data
                    val bitmap: Bitmap =
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity?.contentResolver, selectedImageUri)
                        binding.loginImageRound.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        binding.loginImage.alpha=0f
                    }else{
                        binding.loginImage.visibility=INVISIBLE
                    }
    //                val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
    //                binding.loginImage.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
                }catch(ex:Exception){
                    Toast.makeText(activity, ex.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }


            }else{
                if(requestCode==0){Toast.makeText(activity,"resultCode ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
                if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){Toast.makeText(activity,"resultCode error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}

                if(data==null){
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Data is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

            }
        }


       private fun registerAUser(binding: FragmentRegisterBinding){
           val phno : String = binding.loginPhno.text.toString()
           val name : String = binding.loginName.text.toString()
            if(phno.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() ){
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Phone number/Name should not be empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return
            }
           if(phno.length!=10) {
               Toast.makeText(activity,"Phone number should be 10 numbers",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               return
           }

           verify("+91$phno")

       }

        private fun verify(phno: String) {
            verificationCallbacks()
            Log.i("ph",phno)
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phno, // Phone number to verify
                60, // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
                this, // Activity (for callback binding)
                callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            Log.i("ph","Code Sent")
        }


        private fun verificationCallbacks (){
            callbacks= object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){
                override fun onCodeSent(p0: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(p0, p1)
                    Log.i("ph","On Code Sent Cred $p0")

                }

                override fun onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(p0: String) {
                    super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(p0)

                }

                override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                    Log.i("ph","Sign in verification callback")
                   signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(p0)
                }

                override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
                    if (p0 is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity,"Invalid request",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else if (p0 is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity,"Quota Over contact Developer",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential){
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<AuthResult> ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                        val user = task.result?.user
                        // ...
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                        }
                    }
                }

        }


    }
```

After Trail and error my error goes away after i put MainActivity() in the "activity" place, but i'm not receiving OTP if and the code is not going into OnCodeSent function.(I've enabled phone Auth on my console)

Can someone help here.

Answer (score 0):

When i changed my authtication system from mail to phone number, I've forget to reconnect my app to firebase.

After reconnecting everthing works fine